# Electron Application Displays White Screen but Renders on CentOS 8

Tags: javascript, centos, electron, chromium, centos8

My Electron application is displaying a white screen on CentOS 8, but when I hover over areas of the application, the cursor will change to a button click cursor or a text cursor which tells me that the components are rendering. When I have the application start with dev tools open, it is also just a white screen. The application is working fine when running in development mode. Does anyone know what the issue is?

The application is working on CentOS 7 and various Windows versions. The application and platforms are both 64-bit.

Answer (score 0):

It happened to me before. The problem was in the path of my css files images. Make sure that your path starts with './'. For some reason it was working on development but after packaging the app stopped working.

Example:

Instead of

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
```

do

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./styles.css">
```